# Simply Javascript Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I simply want to display a notification in javascript once someone open the page for the first time (1yr expiredate).

```
var CookieDate = new Date;
CookieDate.setFullYear(CookieDate.getFullYear( ) +1);
document.cookie = 'info=true; expires=' + CookieDate.toGMTString( ) + ';';
```

After that i try to read the cookie with

```
var x = document.cookie;
if x == "true" {..}else{...}
```

but i never get anything
even if i try to go with

```
var x = document.cookie;
alert(x)
```

this ends up empty.

(Jquery is no option)

Comment: well `document.cookie` does not return the last cookie stored.. but all cookies available

Comment: yes but so the alert(x) should not be empty, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: Indeed Fabian, is your code running on the same domain?

Comment: Yes it does (currently all local)

Comment: Try using `jquery cookie` plugin to read the value. It may help.